# How to run a timer in background in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my app I want to set a timer to calculate the working time. My timer is working fine but when I switch to another page then it stops working. How to run the timer and calculate total time run in the background. Here is my code

```cs
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

private void WorkClockStart(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(LaborClock.Text == "Start Work Clock")
    {
        LaborClock.Text = "Stop Work Clock";

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), () =>
        {
            st.Start();
            return false;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        st.Stop();
        long elapsed = st.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        var sec = elapsed / 1000;
        DisplayAlert("Message", "Worked Time(Sec): " + sec, "ok");
        LaborClock.Text = "Start Work Clock";
        st.Reset();
    } 
}
```

How to achieve this in `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: Move your `Stopwatch` variable to the application (App.cs) level so it is not being recreated every time this page is create.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use a timer? Just store the `DateTime.Now` in a variable when you start your watch and compute the delta with `DateTime.Now` when you stop it.
Then you can store wherever you want (in a `static` variable for example or in App.cs if you want depending on your requirement)

Comment: To add to Daniel's good answer. Timers are unreliable on the mobile platform. There are restrictions on long running background threads based on your app's state and platform. Datetime deltas for that reason are a far superior approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel you can use `DateTime` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`, Like the below code.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( async() =>
                        {
                                var time = DateTime.Now;
                                var counter = 30;
                                transactionItem.RetryCount = 30;
                                do
                                {
                                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                                    counter = Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - time.AddSeconds(29)).Seconds);

                                 } while (counter != 0 && time.AddSeconds(29) > DateTime.Now);
                        });
```